# На codewars после прохождения всех тестов выскакивает ошибка. Регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
function solution(str, ending){
  let reg = new RegExp(ending+'$')
  if(str.match(reg)!==null){return true;}
  else{return false;}
}
```

Задание состоит в том, чтобы найти в конце строки совпадение и вывести `true` || `false`. 12 тестов проходит, а потом получаю это:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /:-($/: Unterminated group
    at new RegExp
    at solution
    at check
    at
```

**Не могу понять, что не так с моей регуляркой. Ткните носом (пожалуйста)**

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем создавать регулярное выражение из произвольной строки, нужно экранировать все символы, которые имеют особое значение в регулярках. В данном случае тест пытается найти смайлик с одной скобкой, но скобка служит особым символом в регулярках (наример, выделяет группу), и открывающая скобка без закрывающей будет ошибкой. Составьте список [всех особых символов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters) и экранируйте их.

Кстати, вам обязательно решать с регуляркой? Не проще ли будет с [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)?